# Generating RDoc fails with Directory .ext/rdoc already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc, ruby-enterprise-edition

I'm just installing Ruby Enterprise and cannot change the output directory for this crashing command called by Ruby Enterprise installer.

So how do I delete the directory to satisfy this exception:

Generating RDoc documentation
./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb  ./runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- "./bin/rdoc" --all --ri --op ".ext/rdoc" "."

Directory .ext/rdoc already exists, but it looks like it
isn't an RDoc directory. Because RDoc doesn't want to risk
destroying any of your existing files, you'll need to
specify a different output directory name (using the
--op  option).

Comment: no one is here to help us, the same issue happens to me installing ruby 1.9.2 :-)

Comment: same problem, installed by rvm. help~!

Answer (score 1):

You can most likely remove /opt/ruby-enterprise-edition-#{your_version}/.ext/rdoc and try again.

(Just guessing - I got this by reading ruby-enterprise-edition-1.8.7-2011.03.tar.gz: installer.rb line 215, and source/configure line 10872.)

Comment: Thanks for this--I just received this error with MRI 2.1.1p76, and simply deleting .ext/rdoc and running make again got me a Ruby and some docs.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, if you can live without the developer docs then this workaround might help: http://groups.google.com/group/emm-ruby/browse_thread/thread/84f727edc32ac20e?pli=1

Running the installer like this `sudo ./installer --auto=/usr/local/ruby-enterprise --no-dev-docs`